# Icon showing wrong react-native-vector-icon (icomoon)

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I need to show SVG icons inside my application, I did the entire process of installing the react-native-vector-icons library and configuring icomon. Also, I went to the icomon website and created my font files. But when I use it, the application renders an icon different from the one I should be reloaded by the file.

config icomon

```
import { createIconSetFromIcoMoon } from 'react-native-vector-icons';
import icoMoonConfig from '../../assets/customIcons/selection.json';

export default createIconSetFromIcoMoon(
  icoMoonConfig,
);
```

icon that should be loaded.

[image]

icon being loaded

[image]

My code

```
export function ItemMenuDropdown({ item }) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Container onPress={() => navigation.navigate(item.navigation)}>
      <Content>
        <CustomIcon name="pencil" size={normalize(18)} color="#F68B1F" />
        <Text>{item.item}</Text>
      </Content>
    </Container>
  )
```

I've looked for several solutions here on the site, but I haven't found one that works. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your `selection.json` file. It's either out of date or you're having some kind of cache problem. Maybe you want to try the same operation using this module.

[react-icomoon](https://github.com/aykutkardas/react-icomoon#react-native---demo)